# How to manage stopping a Service with a long-running onDestroy?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android Service class which has a long running onDestroy. I need to prevent this as it can cause a hang when there are activities running.

It seems some people are happy starting a thread/AsyncTask in the onDestroy method to hold the long running code, though I'm concerned that the threads may be killed. Another solution may be to use startService instead of stopService with an intent that tells the service to start a shutdown thread which calls stopSelf at the end.

Are any of these solutions sensible, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shutdown Intent is a reasonable way to go here.

Starting another Thread in onDestroy is a bad idea though. It might be called or not called when you don't expect or want it.

---

Edit: **To persist important information neither of these ways is a good idea.**
You cannot assure that these methods actually get run before your process is killed. For non-important data you could of course go these ways, but you'd better persist your data as soon as you get it, or at least within a fixed interval (if you have a continous data input).

From the [official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29):

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here.
>
> This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

And here the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy%28%29) specifcally for services:

> Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed. The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead.

(I've included the Activities documentation, because it is more precise)

Comment: `It might be called or not called when you don't expect or want it.` - I would not agree that it's a bad idea to use it. If the call comes - you have to free resources, not matter if you like it or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No doubt the application could be killed at any time, so indeed the important data should be saved ASAP. Some data I'm saving is non-critical. Other data may be more important. Unfortunately I'm forking an existing project which is complex, so what I'll do is go through and ensure that the existing code is saving the data when required.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that there is no absolute guarantee for `onDestroy` to be executed.

> It seems some people are happy starting a thread/AsyncTask in the onDestroy method to hold the long running code, though I'm concerned that the threads may be killed.

I would assume that you're trying to either free some resources or send some sort of message to server.

In case of resources there is no need worry - if you'll start new thread it will be killed only together with hosting process (your app). If that would happen - it's ok, system will release resources for you.

In case of server message - that is a bit more complicated. I like your idea with sending command to a `Service` instead of calling `stopService`. Other option would be to start another tear-down `Service` from your `onDestroy` which will perform long running operation and shut down itself.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I've heard before that onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called, but I've never seen this in the docs. Do you know of any official documentation on this? I need to save some data to storage, so it does seem as if using an Intent makes sense to ensure the save operation completes before the Service is stopped. There is a chance that an activity would want the Service to run again whilst it is being stopped. Perhaps in this case the Service could schedule itself to restart after it has stopped.

Comment: @MatthewMitchell it is not documented, but your process can be just killed by the system in case of: it takes too long to complete, it crashes, user force-stops the app, etc. It is up to system, so it's not strictly defined. I would say it is bad idea to save data in `onDestroy`, no matter how you would implement it. It would be more reliable if you'll save data as soon as possible - either directly after you obtained the data or at some interval.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev It is actually documented, but only for activities. But it also applies to services - see my answer

Comment: @F43nd1r it is still documentation for `Activity`, not `Service` - that's what I meant by `not documented`. However, idea there is the same - do not save stuff in `onDestroy`.